# How to set properties in XML attribute values

Tags: xml, izpack

The below question is for izpack package. This happened when I was trying to use the maven izpack plugin.

I have a XML element

```
<file src="../${project.name}-${project.name}.zip" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/"
    unpack="true" />
```

The value of the attribute is set as ../${project.name}-${project.name}.zip, but how do I actually set the properties value for the attributes?

Comment: This is not an XML question per se. It looks as though this may be an XML instance defining an installation package (is it izpack?). Your question is likely about how that particular installation packaging system works. If you tag the question to refer to the installation packaging system instead of xml, and explain more clearly what you are trying to do, you may find someone who can help.

Comment: You're right its in fact for the izpack package. I indeed found the issue and will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The issue was I was using 5.0.10beta version of the maven izpack plugin and it had issues parsing the maven attributes in the xml file. It is resolved by simply going to 5.0.11beta-SNAPSHOT.